# How to select text when using FullCalendar and SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, slickgrid

I have a page with [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) on it and I wanted to add a [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) to show date-based data in calendar form to augment the table (grid) display.

This worked fine (grid shows and calendar shows), but I noticed that I can no longer highlight and select text on the page after calling `fullCalendar()`

I identified root cause script as `jquery.event.drag` from [ThreeDubMedia](https://github.com/threedubmedia/jquery.threedubmedia) which is required for SlickGrid (it throws exception if `jquery.event.drag` lib is not loaded)

However, I'm having trouble finding a fix or even a hack to get this working without breaking other stuff (like SlickGrid functionality). I've been messing with FullCalendar options and even experimentally hacked some of the `mousedown` and `selectstart` handling code, but that didn't help. I also poked around with `jquery.event.drag` methods but I haven't had luck fixing the text selection issue while retaining the SlickGrid functionality that my users want (like being able to drag columns around and stuff).

So definitely some kind of integration issue but I'm not sure where the fault is.. it is weird that `jquery.event.drag` gives me zero problems until I actually create (render) the FullCalendar (by calling `fullCalendar()`), so maybe FullCalendar is to blame. It does proxy several events like `mousemove`, `mouseup`, and `selectstart`, but `jquery.event.drag` also can `hijack` events.. ugh.

Anybody have fix for this? Thanks.

Fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4kLf8jk5/

Clone of above Fiddle, but with call  to `.fullCalendar()` commented out: http://jsfiddle.net/4kLf8jk5/2/

(These are minimalist examples but suffice to demonstrate the issue)

Answer (score 1):

$("#calendar").fullCalendar();
$(document).unbind("dragstart");

Comment: thanks but is there way to do it more generically or permanently? this works until the user changes months or changes from day/week view, and then `dragstart` apparently gets wired up again

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [6pac repo](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid)?
This has a version of `jquery.event.drag` and `..drop` updated for jquery version 2.x and 3.x and other small bugfixes. Might be worth a try before further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.0 of Slickgrid has recently been release that drops the jQueryUI dependency, including the drag and drop files mentioned above. This should make the drag and drop event hooks more consistent.